# Only output the ROC curve in SAS

Tags: sas, logistic-regression, roc, ods, sas-studio

I am looking to create a pdf with 4 nice graphs for different analysis. My question is, how do I output only the ROC curve for my logistic regression?

I use the following code

```
            TITLE2 JUSTIFY=CENTER "Rank ordering characteristic curve (ROC)"; 
            ODS GRAPHICS ON;
                PROC LOGISTIC 
                    DATA = input
                    plots(only)=(roc(id=obs))
            ;
            MODEL y
                (Event = '1')=  x   
                    /
                SELECTION=NONE
                LINK=LOGIT;
            RUN;
            QUIT;
            ODS GRAPHICS OFF;
```

and a dummy dataset can be imagined using this

```
DATA HAVE;
    DO I = 1 TO 100;
        Y = RAND('integer',0,1);
        x = ranuni(i);
        output;
    end;
run;
```

Thanks

EDIT: just to be explicit, I'm looking to output just a plot of the ROC curve and nothing else, i.e. the tables containing the somers' D etc.

Comment: Agree with Reeza's answer below.  But if you want to make a more customized ROC curve, sometimes it's worth outputting the sensitivity/specificity values and making your own plot via SGPLOT or GTL.

Comment: also very valid, thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
ODS SELECT ROCCURVE;
```

`ODS SELECT` allows you to control the output and include only the tables/output you want. 
You can wrap your code in `ODS TRACE ON`, `ODS TRACE OFF` to find out what the table name, or check the [documentation](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=statug&docsetTarget=statug_logistic_details98.htm&docsetVersion=14.3&locale=en).